# Transform from odom_frame to world_frame

Tags: gps, transforms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a dense 3d model of an indoor, gps-denied, scene traversed by a MAV. The map produces its own odometry, which is good enough for navigation but not precise enough for 3d reconstruction. I can extract, out of the images taken by the MAV, precise poses with [openmvg](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html), but I'd like to make use of the odometry poses estimated by the MAV. OpenMVG allows the introduction of prior poses to its methods (see [here](https://openmvg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/software/Geodesy/geodesy/#non-rigid-registration-adaptive-registration-sfm)), but they need to be included in the EXIF data of the images in form of GPS coordinates.

So I need to convert coordinates in the `odom_frame` to coordinates in the `world_frame`. I could also provide the actual GPS coordinates of the first pose, so that I could place the scene in the world, but that's not important.

I've been searching in ROS documentation and all the transformations I've found seem to be from `world_frame` to `odom_frame`, but this task looks like quite simple, so I guess there must be some ROS module which does the job.

What should I do in order to express `odom_frame` coordinates in `world_frame` coordinates?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273032/transform-from-odom_frame-to-world_frame/) by [capstayn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26504/capstayn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The transform from `odom` to `world` is the inverse of the transform from `world` to `odom` if you have one you have the other. I'd recommend reading through the [tf2 tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials) which can help you learn about working with transforms and coordinate frames.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1